# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=\int\limits_{1}^{n} \frac{e^{-xy}}{1+y^2} dy$

Tags: real-analysis

Given this succession of function $f_n(x)$ are continuous functions?
fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$,  $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f_n(x) $ depends from the value of $x$?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$ to $f(x)=\int_1^{\infty} \frac {e^{-xy}} {1+y^{2}} dy$ and it tends to $\infty$ at each point $x \in (-\infty,0)$.

Uniform convergence for $x \geq 0$ comes from the facts that $e^{-xy} \leq 1$ and $\int_1^{\infty} \frac 1 {1+y^{2}} dy <\infty$.